# Display information related to row when mouse hovers over in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display information unique to a row in a table whenever a user hovers their mouse over it. I'm getting close to accomplishing this by pulling information from the database and then using erb to put that information in a div however, the problem I'm having is that the same information of 1 row is being displayed for all of them.

I'm using a class for the row and a class for the div that contains the popup. I use jQuery to get mouse movement and also show and hide whenever the mouse hovers over the row.

```
<div class="popup">
    <h4>Blah</h4>
    <% for car in dealership.cars do %>
      <p>
      <%= information about row %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>


  <tr class="row" data-link="<%= dealership_path(vendor)%>" style="cursor: pointer;">
     <td><%= can_link_to :show, vendor, vendor.id, dealership_path(vendor), {} %></td>
     <td>
     </td>
     <td>Blah</td>
     <td>Blahblah</td>
     <td>Blah</td>
  </tr>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var noteSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.popup');
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".row").hover(function() {
        $(".popup").show();
        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
                y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
            for (var i = 0; i < noteSpans.length; i++) {
                noteSpans[i].style.top = y;
                noteSpans[i].style.left = x;
            }
        };
    }, function() {
        $(".popup").hide();
    });
    });

    $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
      window.location = $(this).data("link")
    })
  </script>

.popup {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color: #13a8ac;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 8px;
  position: fixed;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your existing code? That would make it easier for us to pinpoint the bug.

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that now.

Comment: From what it sounds like, you are trying to display unique information for different rows on a jquery mouse hover by the user.  You are trying to accomplish this with data stored in ruby variables which you are trying to display via erb tags in the view.  The problem here is that once set initially, the erb variables will need a refresh of the html page to update.  Looking forward to seeing your code.

Comment: Okay I just added the code.

Comment: Do you have a separate `<div class="popup">` for every `<tr>`, or just a single one on the entire page?

Comment: Is this a partial that's inside a loop?  you probably need something like a unique `id` HTML attribute per row and the script needs to inspect which row's `id` it is hovering over and display that one.

Comment: Yes. All the code is in a partial file which is being rendered in a different view, generating all the <tr>

Comment: Side note: `dealership.cars each do |car|` is preferred over `for car in dealership.cars`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your `<div class="popup">` element in a partial that gets rendered multiple times on the same page, you will end up with several `<div class="popup">` elements in total.

Not only that, but you are also repeating your `<script>` tag as many times as there are rows on the page, which will result in multiple event handlers being attached to `.popup` and `tr[data-link]` where just a single one would be enough (and correct).

**Solution:**

Move your `.popup` `<div>` *as well as* your `<script>` block out of the partial, into the main template. Then, add the content that you would like to display in the tooltip to a hidden `<div>` inside the `<tr>` elements. An example:

```
<tr class="row" data-link="<%= dealership_path(vendor)%>">
  <div class="row-tooltip" style="display: none">
    <h4>Blah</h4>
    <% for car in dealership.cars do %>
      <p><%= information about row %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Then, in the main template, change the JavaScript code so that it dynamically displays the right content in the `.popup` `<div>` when the mouse hovers a particular `<tr>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".row").hover(
      function() {
        $(".popup").html(
          $(".row-tooltip", this).html()
        );

        $(".popup").show();

        $(window).on("mousemove.tooltip", function(e) {
          var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
              y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
          $(".popup").css({
            top: y,
            left: x,
          });
        });
      },
      function() {
        $(".popup").hide();
        $(window).off("mousemove.tooltip");
      }
     );
  });

  $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("link")
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding. Why move the div with the popup outside of the partial and into the other view? The <tr> row element is in the partial yet in your answer you have the popup div inside the row element which you say to put it into the other view? Do you mean to put the div inside the <tr> element that is in the partial and then move the js into the other view?

Comment: @buttonSmasher96 In his answer, he has 1 `.popup` div *outside* of the partials and then has a `.row-tooltip` div inside the table row *inside* the partial. When you `hover` he is then grabbing the content from `.row-tooltip` and placing it into `.popup` and then showing `.popup`

Comment: Not sure why but it's still not working for me. I put the js in the template and moved the .popup div into the template as well. I even put the .popup div between my <tbody> tags yet I still wasn't able to display the popup.

Comment: Maybe I confused you guys but I want to display a popup for each row whenever it is moused over. This popup will then contain unique information pertaining to that specific row. So far with the help of Máté Solymosi I was only able to display a small chunk of the div when hovered over. When I choose inspect element on firefox, it shows that the style of the divs are "display: none"